# Servlets and AJAX communication

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, communication

I do have a communication problem here between my Java servlet and an Ajax request. more about it:

Absolute path to the index.html (including JavaScript/Ajax request):
http://localhost:9080/chat/index.html

In the same folder the servlet:
`MyChat.class`

And the Request is working like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:9080/chat";

var name = document.getElementById("username").getAttribute("value");
var message = document.getElementById("message").getAttribute("value");

var tosend = name+","+message;

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(tosend);
request.onreadystatechange = interpretRequest;
```

I'm having a formula where a user just types in the name and the message and `username` and `message` are `<input>` tags in my HTML file. The Ajax request works, that's sure, but it doesn't communicate with the servlet. I also don't have an idea where the output from `System.out.println()` goes. No log file is filled... And the servlet looks like this:

```js
public class MyChat extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private ArrayList<String> myMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        BufferedReader r = request.getReader();

        while(r.readLine() != null)
        {
                        // split the words at the ','
            String[] tmp = r.readLine().split(".\\s");
            myMessages.add(tmp[0]+" "+tmp[1]);
        }
                
        //response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                Iterator<String> it = myMessages.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            out.println(it.next());
                        System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
    
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling the servlet from the address bar to find out if the problem is in the JavaScript or the servlet. (Something like localhost:9080/chat/index.html?username=Lenni)

Comment: won't work because i'm getting the username from an input tag. looks like: <input id="username" value=""/>

Comment: Well, then just dumb it down a little and return a Hello World and try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you've specified isn't to your servlet.

Just like the URL to the index page is `http://<server>:<port>/<webapp name>/<resource>` the URL to your servlet needs a mapping in the `web.xml` file that corresponds to the `<resource>` part of the url.

For example, if you had a controller servlet you'd expect something like the following in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The URLs that would invoke the 'controller' servlet would then follow the form `http://<server>:<port>/<webapp name>/<anything>.do`.

Comment: just added the web.xml. it's within the folder where the html file is and my class file. as i start the request i'm getting a request status that is not 200 so ... request fails

Comment: The web.xml file need to be in a WEB-INF directory in the root of the web app.  Take a look at this tutorial for the details on packaging a web app - http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WebComponents.html

Comment: and where do i have to place the class file then? :-(

Comment: The classes go in WEB-INF/classes.  If you use ANT the WAR task will do it all for you.